# How to define optimal chunks for a sequence compression?

Tags: compression, archive, information-theory

I have a long sequence of symbols. I would like to find "words" in this sequence. There are two extremes in defining "words". In the first case I could say that every symbol is a "word". In the second case I could say that the whole sequence is a single large "word".

However, I would like define words such that each I can compress the data as much as possible. In the two above given extreme cases it is obviously not the case. In the first case the "archive" would be identical to the original sequence. In the second case the archive will contain a code for just one single word (which is nice) but the world itself requires as much place as the original sequence.

So, my question is if this problem can be properly formalised and if it is the case, how is it called and how is it solved.

---

**ADDED:**

I guess the problem is related to the problem of finding a sub-sequence that is, on one hand, happens very frequently and, on the other hand, is long. In this case replacing it by a short code can reduce the length of the original sequence significantly. However, I am not sure of a greedy search for "words" (one by one) provides an optimal solution.

Comment: OK, I'll bite again, even though you didn't react to the responses to your previous question. What you seem to be interested in right now are dictionary-based methods of compression (Ch.6 in the book i mentioned last time). For what you seek, a sliding window algorithm would fit, prime example of which are the various Lempel-Ziv variants in existence (e.g. zlib, lzma, etc.). From what I've seen regarding optimizing the search for repeated strings: hashing, binary trees, prefix trees, optimal parsing.

Comment: We can compute some pretty tight bounds for the theoretically achievable compression for certain data distributions. However, no known compression algorithm has ever come close to that bound (ignoring some special cases due to lack of generality). In that sense, we know that Lempel-Ziv, and by extension greedy dictionary compression, is non-optimal.

Comment: However, Lempel-Ziv and related algorithms work very well on a number of different data types. In fact, other compression approaches typically focus on only one particular data type, where they then excel (mp3/mp4/jpeg/etc). In that sense, the suggestion by @DanMašek to use LZW is entirely rational, as you have not divulged any details about your data.